# codeigniter - pyrocms intercept and modify all queries; extending active record

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

Is there a way to catch all queries and modify them before being sent to the db outside of modifying `DB_active_record.php`? This would be ideal, though I'm not averse to modifying this file if it's the only option.

I could just call this stuff from the models, but would feel better if this was something that was done in the background so as not to leave room for forgetting when and where it's happening; it'd be best to have it done in the background.

I'm using a library to encrypt query data. In the lib, I'm checking for certain keys to not encrypt, so it's not just a matter of encrypting all data, but some data in each query.

For example, modifying `insert()` like so:

```
function insert($table = '', $set = NULL)
{
    if ( ! is_null($set))
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('my_encrypt');
        $set = $this->CI->my_encrypt->encrypt_query($set);
        $this->set($set);
    }
```

works correctly to encrypt the data before sending to the db. However, this does nothing for updates/sets nor decryption.

Is there a way to set up an intermediary something or other that acts as a go-between between models and active record where I could encrypt and decrypt the relevant data before sending it on to AR or back to the model?

Thanks.

---

### UPDATE:

So following the guide below, I was able to get this working. I'm using pyroCMS (ver. 1.3.2 community; CI version 2.0.2) which had already done some of the legwork.

Heres what I did.

`system/cms/core/MY_Loader.php` extends `MX_loader` which extends `CI_Loader`; so `MX_Loader` is what needs to be modified.

---

`system/cms/libraries/MX/Loader.php`

change `public function database()` to:

```
public function database($params = '', $return = FALSE, $active_record = NULL) {
    log_message('debug', 'db loader from MX/Loader');

    // Grab the super object
    $CI =& get_instance();

    // Do we even need to load the database class?
    if (class_exists('CI_DB') AND $return == FALSE AND $active_record == NULL AND isset($CI->db) AND is_object($CI->db)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    require_once(BASEPATH.'database/DB'.EXT);

    // Load the DB class
    $db =& DB($params, $active_record);

    //get the driver name, set its path and load er up
    $my_driver = config_item('subclass_prefix').'DB_'.$db->dbdriver.'_driver';
    $my_driver_file = APPPATH.'core/'.$my_driver.EXT;

    if (file_exists($my_driver_file)) {
        require_once($my_driver_file);
        $db = new $my_driver(get_object_vars($db));
    }

    if ($return === TRUE) {
        return $db;
    }

    CI::$APP->db = DB($params, $active_record);
    return CI::$APP->db;
}
```

The important difference here from the article linked in the accepted answer is the setting of the db vars as pyro does it differently from regular CI.

Then in `system/cms/core` add the customized driver file `MY_DB_mysql_driver.php`. This will then be loaded and these methods will be available in all models. Also, methods in here using the same name as in `DB_active_rec.php` will take precedence. e.g. adding an `insert` method in MY_DB_mysql_driver.php will override the insert method in `DB_active_rec.php`.

Comment: contrary to my note below you are correct in what you've said here in the update regarding how overrides work, I think you may just be confused (if at all) about the why more than the what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default you cannot extend the active record class. You can however, extend the active record class **after** extending the loader class database call to allow it:

Instructions & code here: http://www.simonemms.com/code/extending-the-codeigniter-database-class/

Comment: So I'm not clear... does this allow me to usurp every query run through active record? Because it doesn't look like it. It looks like it is essentially creating a pseudo-helper to share methods across all models. Am I missing something?

Comment: It allows you to extend the active record class, if you can do that you can do what ever you want to the underlying queries before they are sent to the server.

Comment: In other words you can override the `_compile_select` (for the where parts), `_insert` (for inserts), `_update` (for updates) etc etc these are base functions you need to update each of them as from there they call `query()` Unless you want to parse everything back out of the sql to do your encryption in `query()` (you don't) you may as well update each function where its pre compiled sql.

Comment: eggggggcelent. I'm actually using pyroCMS which has already extended the Loader class so it was just a matter of modifying that. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside: can you explain _why_ this sort of method overriding works in CI? Is it a last-out type thing where the last thing executed takes precedence?

Comment: It essentially `include`'s all the classes but only initializes the one you need based on config settings, the overriding is basic object oriented php making use of `extend` make sense? not quite sure what you're asking now

Comment: Yeah I meant the OOP stuff. I dug around and read some docs on method overriding. I'm not 100%, but it seems that it is indeed last out takes precedence. e.g. the last `insert` of all the possible inserts in all possible classes (in this case, just DB_active_record.php and MY_DB_mysql_driver.php), the last to be called will be the one evaluated. Thanks.

Comment: hmm not quite, its more of a least common denominator type deal, if you initialise an instance of `DB_active_record` it will use the `insert` from that class object regardless of what has been loaded, if you initialise a `DB_mysql_driver` (which `extends DB_active_record`) it will use the insert from the driver (if available, otherwise it will use the parent object's). You have to load (read: `include`|`require`) `DB_active_record` first as `DB_mysql_driver` `extends` the former.

Comment: So it's kinda like an order of nesting type thing? e.g. if I have class1,class2 extends class1, class3 extends class2 and all 3 classes have a foo() method, the class3 foo() will override all other foo() methods. So conceptually, thinking left-to-right, the furthest right takes precedence a'la: http://i.imgur.com/6qjHN.png ? Much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't extend the active record class without modifying the core (which really sucks). So, you have a couple of options:

- Create a base model that implements the functionality you want, and extend that with your various models **(this way you only do it once)**
- Add the functionality to each model **(not DRY)**
- Overwrite the core files **(not ideal)** - it's only a few lines of code: http://robotslacker.com/2011/05/extending-codeigniters-active-record-class/